# MAX1472 Source impedance

Tags: rf

I'm sure I'm just being dense (or missing some really basic concept) but, in designing an antenna matching network for the MAX1472, I can't seem to find a specification for what the impedance at the output pin ought to be. Is this a fixed number or somehow related to the frequency I'm running at? I'm just not getting how that would be determined.

I suspect this is probably where a VNA would come in handy but they are well beyond my budget and I wouldn't know how to use it if I had one lol.

The datasheet for the device in question: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1472.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet says the optimum loading at the output of the PA is between 100 and 150 ohms with a 2.7V supply (page 6).

> The output-matching network suppresses the carrier harmonics
>   and transforms the antenna impedance to an
>   optimal impedance at PAOUT (pin 4), which is between
>   100Ω and 150Ω for a 2.7V supply.

So aim for something like 125 ohms.

Matching networks are frequency sensitive.

The misleadingly-named [Application Note 1954](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN1954.pdf) "Designing Output-Matching Networks for the MAX1472 ASK Transmitter" presents several pre-designed networks for matching to a 50\$\Omega\$ antenna at frequently-used frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Second sentence on the datasheet. :)

> The MAX1472 supports data rates up to 100kbps, and adjustable output power to  more than +10dBm into a 50Ω load.

The datasheet also has application examples on how to do impedance matching for PCB antennas.

Comment: I assumed that was referring to the target (antennas) impedance not necessarily the impedance at the devices output?